# Getting rid of Twitter Bootstrap span margin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, margin

I am using bootstrap and trying to make two span appear side by side while also removing the white margin between spans.
If I do the code, there is a white margin between each span

My code is :

```
<li class="span4" >
    <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="img/placeholder-360x200.jpg" alt="product name">
             <div class="container row-fluid">  
                  <b>
                     <span class="span6 nospace" id="one"> <font size ="5px"><i>PHP 100,000</i></span>

                     <span class="span6 nospace pull-right" id="two" >50% Off </span>
                               </font>
                </b>

              </div>
           <div class="caption">

                <p>
                  Few attractive words about your product.Few attractive words about your product.
                </p>

              </div>

                  <div class="widget-footer">
                <p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy now</a>&nbsp;
                  <a href="product.html" class="btn">Read more</a>
                </p>
                  </div>  

            </div>
          </li>
```

While I tried adding this on CSS:

```
.nospace{
```

margin-left: 0;
}

Here is what my code gives me:

[image]

Here is what I am trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should use `span` class inside `row-fluid` class to get rid of margin

Comment: do you mean something like this: 
 
<div class="row-fluid">
 <div class="span4"></div>
</div>

Comment: best practice will be container-> row-fluid -> span

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm a bit slow, I just started in Front-end coding. And

Comment: its ok i have 7 years experience in front end coding and i still consider my self learner

Comment: I just started in Front-end coding. And what I think you me to do is something like this?

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
.span6.nospace{
margin-left:0;
}
```

## ============================================

**or used** to this way  but this is bed practice

```
.nospace{margin-left:0 !important;} //
```

Comment: you are using this way  <div class="row-fluid"> <div class="span6">PHP 100,000</div>  <div class="span6 nospace">50% off</div> </div>

Answer (score 0):

in your coding `
             *PHP 100,000*

```
        <span class="span6 nospace pull-right" id="two" >50% Off </span>`
```

remove pull-right please avoid using pull-right or pull-left in twitter bootstrap.

Comment: thank you, I have removed the pull-right class, but it only affected the 'PHP 100,000' text.

Comment: give the link,cant use jsfiddle

Comment: try giving margin-left:0 to the id #two and also try well class instead of nospace